# Conditional pdf of a random variable that is a function of other random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given a pair of random variables $X,Y$, the conditional pdf of $Y$ given $X=x$ is defined by $$f(y\mid x) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$$

Now, suppose $Z$ is another random variable and $Y=g(X,Z)$. Then fixing $X=x$, $Y$ is distributed as $g(x, Z)$. I am guessing it should be true that the pdf of $g(x, Z)$ should be $f(y\mid x)$. Is this true and how would one prove this?

Comment: The pdf of $g(x, Z)$ will be related to $f(y \mid x)$, but not necessarily equal. You can even take a simpler example, like $Y = 2Z$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to say something about the relationship between $X$ and $Z$. Take $Y=g(X,Z)=Z$, then you don't generally have the pdf of $g(x,Z)=Z$ equaling the conditional pdf of $Z$ given $X=x$.

Comment: Why not? For instance, if $X$ and $Z$ are independent and $Y=Z$, $f(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)=f_X(x)f_Z(z)$. Then $f(y|x)=g(z)$. I know I assumed independence here but I don't see a counterexample in the case you propose. Am I missing something here?